# Using CP-SAT Solver for non-linear objective function

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm trying to use CP-SAT solver with some variables: `x`,`y`. I want to maximise an objective function of the form `x**2-y*x` with some constraints. I'm getting

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'IntVar' and
>   'int'

error messages. Am I correct in assuming I cannot use nonlinear objective function for CP-SAT, as I couldn't find any documentation or examples that did employ nonlinear objectives? Or is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an intermediate variable using AddMultiplicationEquality(x2, [x, x])

Comment: It seems to be AddProdEquality nowadays.

Comment: I think it was deprecated in favor of MultiplicationEq

Comment: Indeed, the non deprecated API is AddMultiplicationEquality